# Process to Apply Schengen Visit Visa for Finland from Pakistan - 2021

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, finland, pakistan

I recently did some research on the topic but didn't find the clear steps somewhere. So I thought its good idea to share the process that I recently followed while applying for Schengen visit visa for Finland from Pakistan. The steps and document details I followed are mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Finland does not have an embassy in Pakistan, so the visit visa is processed via Netherlands.
2. Book an appointment directly with Netherlands embassy in Pak through vfs.
3. After step 2, you will get an email from Gerry’s Pakistan asking appointment date and applicant contact details. Agree on a date/time that suits you, all your paperwork should be complete before the appointment.
4. Visa Application preparation:

   - Passport (valid during the travel period) – Applicant
   - 2 Pictures (Normally pictures are not needed, Gerry will take your picture) but still good to have. Picture size details are available on Netherland’s website. – Applicant
   - Invitation Letter from Host, this should include the host name, contact, address, purpose of invitation and passport details for the applicant. If host is sponsoring the trip do mentioned the details like “I (host) would be responsible for travel, food, residence etc.”. Get it notarized by digital and population data services agency Finland. – Host
   - Address proof of host: extract from digital and population data services agency Finland mentioning address details or copy of rental contract. – Host
   - Cover Letter by Applicant, this should include the purpose of travel and personal details. Signed by the applicant. – Applicant
   - Travel Insurance covering the duration of trip. – Applicant
   - Travel Itinerary, no need to buy confirm ticket. – Applicant
   - Bank Statement (last 3 to 6 months), For both applicant and Host if host is sponsor. – Applicant & Host
   - Salary Slip (last 3 months), For both applicant and Host if host is sponsor. – Applicant & Host
   - NADRA FRC (Family Registration Certificate in Pak) incase applicant and host are related (parents, grandparents, and children) – Applicant
   - Covid-19 fully vaccinated certificate from NADRA – Applicant
   - Other Supporting documents

     - Land record/Property lease document and its English translation. – Applicant
     - NOC/Leaves approval from employer to travel aboard. – Applicant
     - Any other document which could be used as proof that applicant would return after completing the trip. – Applicant
   - Passport and Finland visa copy of host – Host
   - Schengen Visa Application Form filled and signed by application. – Applicant
   - Print the email from Gerry’s confirming appointment date and time. – Applicant
   - Bring 2 copies of all documents listed above otherwise you would be asked to get it done inside Gerry’s office during your appointment. – Applicant
5. Visit Gerry’s Office on the appointment date and time, it could take 2 to 5 hours there to submit all the documents. (tip: Never opt the option to deliver passport to home address if you have limited days before travel, delivery to home could take a week)
6. You will get an email whenever there is a change in the application status (you can buy SMS option too), It will take 2-3 weeks from the date of submission. In my case I received the passport on 16th calendar day, 4-5 days was taken by the delivery service to deliver the passport to my home address.

Comment: I have a small question: do we need to attach the visa/residence permit of the host, or the certificate of residence is enough?

Comment: Yes, I at least attached the copy of visa (residence permit) and passport from host.